# Identify a client in Channel MSP in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I learn about Hyperledger Fabric but in the part of Channel MSP I still have some questions. Channel MSP is the combination of local MSP and when a client access to channel, how can a peer verify identity of a client? Does a peer need to access to Channel MSP and check a client's identity by himself or he invokes a specific Chaincode to verify?

Answer (score 1):

> how can a peer verify identity of a client?

Client request could be in context of some specific channel, for example chaincode invocation. In such case peer will verify clients access rights based on Channel MSP. In case clients request not in context of specific channel then peer will be consulting local MSP to verify clients identity.

> Does a peer need to access to Channel MSP and check a client's identity by himself or he invokes a specific Chaincode to verify?

As explained above, chaincode invocation done in context of certain channel hence peer will leverage channel MSP to verify client's identity. Peer will do it directly, e.g. without calling additional chaincodes.

Comment: thank you for your answer, as you said a peer will verify client's identity directly so, if there are hundred of client access to him at the same time, how can he manage without using a specific chaincode? and as i remember Channel MSP doesn't contain Access Right, it contains the combination of local MSP. so, to check Access right in Channel MSP, it's not the proper solution.

Comment: ACL in Fabric is signature based, meaning you verify access right based on the client's signing identity, which basically comprised from signature and certificate. Hence you need MSP to verify validity of the certificate and correctness of the signature. The access right per se provided in channel configuration in form of policy. You basically providing signing identity to policy manager to evaluate them, which in turn leverages channel MSP. Also not sure how number of clients matters here, there is cache here to improve efficiency, while why this would imply need for another chaincode?

Comment: "to check Access right in Channel MSP, it's not the proper solution." --- I'm also a bit confused with this argument. Channel MSP is not a combination of local MSP, channel MSP initialized with crypto materials provided in genesis block while peer joins the channel. The crypto materials contains organizations root CA certificates, which used by MSP to attest clients certificates and determine which organization issued given certificate.

Comment: "You basically providing signing identity to policy manager to evaluate them, ...", Can you explain me a bit about policy manager? the policy manager that contain in the independent peers?

Comment: Please read about ACL and policies in documentation: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/access_control.html

Comment: Actually, i haven't read through fabric ACL doc. I know ACL in Hyperledger Composer but i think they are the same. ACL in fabric has two level one is for peer and channel and Hyperledger Composer does. So, how to check Channel ACL, does a peer need to invoke a chaincode to check policy in ACL? and you said "Channel MSP initialized with crypto materials...", what is crypto material? I am sorry to ask lots but i still confuse with Channel MSP doesn't use a specific chaincode to verify client identity.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187004/discussion-between-dara-tith-and-artem-barger).

Answer (score 0):

Since I searched through fabric node sdk also composer-rest-server, they provided the MSP class also MSP manager in Fabric-ca-client and Fabric-client. Ex: in case of Hyperledger Composer beside you start network in Fabric-dev-server, you can find lib where building business network listen, call and loopback is in Node_Modules (home/$User/.nvm/versions/node/v8.12.0/lib/node_modules). In conclusion, a peer no need to invoke a specific chaincode for check ACL also client's identity. He can call an existing code in the composer-rest-server.